# Merging of sub variables to fetch constructed variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible that the merging of sub variables fetches the constructed variable?

That's my script:

```js
var a_b_c = 5000;

console.log(a_b_c); // 5000

var el_a = 'a';
var el_b = 'b';
var el_c = 'c';

console.log(el_a + '_' + el_b + '_' + el_c); // logs a_b_c
```

... what I would like to have is though:

```
console.log(el_a+'_'+el_b+'_'+el_c); // 5000
```

Is this anyhow possible?

Here is a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/2ca9skg7/

Comment: `console.log(window[el_a+'_'+el_b+'_'+el_c]);` But you should use an Object of yours, not `window`. `var myVars = { a_b_c: 5000 }; console.log(myVars[...]);`

Comment: what is the use case of it?

Comment: What's a "sub variable"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var a_b_c = 5000;

console.log(a_b_c);

var el_a = 'a';
var el_b = 'b';
var el_c = 'c';

console.log(window[el_a+'_'+el_b+'_'+el_c]);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oa3gw450/

or if it's in a function, you'll probably have to use `eval`:

```js
(() => {
  var a_b_c = 5000;

  console.log(a_b_c);

  var el_a = 'a';
  var el_b = 'b';
  var el_c = 'c';

  console.log(eval(el_a+'_'+el_b+'_'+el_c));
})()
```